# Unity CapsuleCollider2D returns collision with ray casted to right or left when object touches the ground from being airborne

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object with CapsuleCollider2D which uses

```
IsGrounded = CapsuleCollider2D.Cast(Vector2.down, castFilter, groundHits, groundDistance) > 0;
IsOnWall = CapsuleCollider2D.Cast(Vector2.right /*or left*/, castFilter, wallHits, wallDistance) > 0;
```

to determine whether it should flip when is walking and touches the wall:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (touchingDirections.IsGrounded && touchingDirections.IsOnWall)
        {
            FlipDirection();
        }
    }
```

But when the object gets airborne or drops from air at the start of the scene it returns IsOnWall true multiple times when it touches the ground and flips the sprite. Times it returns true on IsOnWall depends on the height from it drops. Why does the raycast to the right result in collision when it touches the ground?

Tried to implement a timer for flips when it touches the ground but unsuccessfully.

Comment: How often are you setting IsOnWall  and IsGrounded ? why are you casting and not just letting the colliders do the job for you?

Comment: How is your `castFilter` configured? You should probably not include the ground layer in there and separate ground from wall and only check for the walls ... I suspect it falls down so fast that for a split second it basically overlaps with the ground and returns it as hit result